# How to inform search engines that my site support multilanguages?

Tags: seo, html, url, multilingual, translation

The website i am working on is translated to 8 languages (English, Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hindi, Russian, Spanish and Portuguese).

Each time the user select a language, the URL stays the same as i am using a combination of defined variables to change the languages. For example, the URL for the English version (mysite.com) looks like the Chinese version.

**My Question:** Do i need to specify a certain HTML tag to inform search engines that my website is in 8 languages? if yes, what are the necessary tags and how to define them?

As an extra question, does this technique in translating the website bad for SEO?

Comment: This recent question faced a similar problem: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32173/google-and-301-302

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely have a different URL for each language for SEO.

In your pages you can use Links in the header to inform the bot or useragent of the other languages:

```
<link rel="Alternate" hreflang="en-US" title="English content" href="/english/page.htm" />
<link rel="Alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" title="Dutch translation" href="/dutch/page.htm" />
```

Using cookies to determine the language is certainly not SEO friendly, nor is it human, blog, twitter, or anything-else friendly (how could someone ever link to a page in a specific language on such a site?). It is also good to have a "[permalink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink)" to support social media propaganda.

Answer (score 1):

There is the "lang" attribute in HTML, which you can add to the parent element: `<html lang="en">` - however [Google basically ignores it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page).

Even if that wasn't the case I don't think your system would ever work, as the same URL would be returning different content. **You should have different URLs for different languages** - either subdomains or separate folders.

Comment: While Google ignores it as Goat linked to, you should still add it to pages for semantic reasons. Some screen readers can announce the page using that language. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11265602/1276124)